# Is Moreau Yosida approximation lipschitz?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, metric-spaces

Let $X$ be a metric space. (You may assume some regularity condition.)

Let $F:X\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a lower semicontinous functional (You may assum some regularity condition.)

Define $I(a)=F(a)+ \frac{d^2(a,c)}{2L}$ for all $a\in X$ and some $c\in X$.

Assume that there exists $m\in X$ such that $I(m)$ is the infimum of $I$ over $X$.

Then, can we conclude that $I(a)-I(m)\leq I(b)-I(m)$ implies that $d(a,m)\leq C\cdot d(b,m)$ for some constant $C$?